# Rails controller method response as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, best-in-place

Im working with a GEM call best_in_place : https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Creation of new todo items are done with:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name, :type => :input, :nil => "Click me to add content!" %>

respond_to :html, :json, :js

def todo_item_fast_create
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(params[:todo_item])
    @todo_item.save
    respond_with @todo_item
end
```

The response code is JSON, but I would like to call a JS template so I can manipulate the DOM, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a view template with filename like this: `todo_item_fast_create.js.erb` this file will be served when that action is called. You might have to add `:remote => true` to the button or link that calls this action.

This is one of my JS files : new.js.erb (called when I schedule a new export).

```
$("#export_modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new")) %>");
<!-- trigger the modal to open -->
$("#export_modal").modal('show');

$("#popover1").popover();
```

That call to `escape_javascript(render("new"))` renders a partial into the js response and I let the js handle updating the DOM.

Comment: Dosen't work, i get this error: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template todo_lists/todo_item_fast_create, application/todo_item_fast_create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.